# Stack of strings. Deleting an even element

Tags: c++, string, stack

everyone!
I'm trying to do such task:
Create stack od strings, by writing several constructors, including copy constructor. All elements are hleds in an array. If an array have fixed size, in case of overloading, increase it. Create pop(), push() functions. Make a function, deleting every even element.

Got problem, after sizing of the stack

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstddef>
using namespace std;

class Stack
{
string *stck; //stack pointer
int sz; //stack size
int ts; //top of the stack

public:    
//constructor
Stack(int size)
{
    size=sz;
    stck = new string[sz];
    ts = -1;
};

//destructor
~Stack() {
delete []stck;
};

 //copy constructor    
Stack (const Stack &ob);
void Push(string itm);
string Pop();
void Show(int sz);

private:
void Resize(int sz);    

};

void Stack::Push(string itm)
{
    if (ts == sz)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is overflow"<<endl;
        Resize(ts);
    }

    else stck[ts++] = itm;
}

string Stack::Pop()
{
    if(ts<0)
    {
        cout<<"Stack is free"<<endl;
        return 0;    
    }
    else return stck[--ts];
}   

void Stack::Show(int sz)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
    {
    std::cout << stck[i] << std::endl;
    }
}    

Stack::Stack (const Stack &ob)
{
    cout<<"Copy constructor allocating stackPtr)"<<endl;
    stck = new string;
    *stck = *ob.stck;
}    

//функция выделения дополнительной памяти
void Stack::Resize(int idx)
{
    int new_size = sz;
    while (new_size < idx)
        new_size *=2;
    string *new_arr = new string[new_size];
    for(int i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        new_arr[i] = stck[i];
    delete[] stck;
    stck = new_arr;
    sz = new_size;
}        


int main()
{
cout<<"Enter the size of the stack"<<endl;
int n;
cin>>n;
Stack mystck(n);
string str;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{
cout<<"Enter an element"<<endl;
cin>>str;
mystck.Push(str);
}

for(int j = 0; j<n; j+2)
{
mystck.Pop();
mystck.Show(n);
}
return 0;
}
```

Can anybody help me with fixing that case?

Comment: In `Stack::Push` it should be  `else stck[++ts] = itm;`

Comment: And in `Stack::Pop` it should be `stck[ts--]`.

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't work either =\ Same mistake